# STM32F4 ISP(bootloader) stacked with PC=0xFFFF_FFFE

Tags: stm32, bootloader, stm32f4

I connect STM32F407's BOOT0 pin to VCC, expecting to download my program via USART1. There is no other external peripheral except UART1,UART2,UART6. However, the STM32CubeProgrammer tells me "Activating device [KO]". Then I double confirm that the Power and USART1 Port are all work well. Next, I send "0x7F"to USART1, but there is no response from USART1, not a single bit.

I boot STM32 from system memory (BOOT0=VCC), and check PC Pointer in STM32CubePorgrammer, and find that this Pointer stacked at 0xFFFF_FFFE, and if I click 'RUN', an error will occur: "Unable to run application".

[Figure1. error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU2Lz.png)

Actually, I have two STM32F407 chips, which are belonging to different production batches. One can boot from SYSTEM MEMORY, another can't( PCBs are exactly the same ).

Why the PC Pointer is stacked here? Is there any possible that the program in system memory is broken?

Comment: Have you checked system bootloader peripheral activation priority? Regarding 0xFFFFFFFE, I would start your search somewhere here: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0419/c/System-Level-Architecture/System-Level-Programmers--Model/ARMv6-M-exception-model/Unrecoverable-exception-cases?lang=en Also, please, embed your picture properly into the question.

Comment: It does not work like this.

Answer (score 0):

[BOOT1=PB2 has to be at log.0](http://efton.sk/STM32/gotcha/g139.html), otherwise the mcu attempts to boot from RAM, and as that has undefined ("random") content upon powerup, it most probably ends up in a lockup.

JW

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've connect BOOT1 to GND already.  In fact, I have two STM32F407 chips, which are belonging to defferent production batches. One can boot from SYSTEM MEMORY, another can't( PCBs are exactly the same ).

Comment: Check hardware, think bad solder joints and shorts. Check if *all* GND/VCC are properly connected including analog, and if you are using a higher-pin-count package, check PDR_ON connection. Check if power supply is rock solid.

Comment: I've check hardware and confirm that there is no hardware problem, because I replace the abnormal STM32F407 on the PCB by a good one, and the new STM32F407 worked well. So is there a possible that the abnormal STM32F407's ISP or internal hardware occured error?

Comment: It might've been a damaged chip, or there might've been a bad solder joint as I've said above.